# Can I make an Enum return something other than an integer?

Tags: c#

If I have the following:

```
public enum TYPE
{
   One = 1,
   Two = 2,
   Three = 3
}
```

When I do:

```
 var a = TYPE.One;
```

I would like it to populate the variable a with a string in the **format "01"**. In other words two digits with a leading zero.

Is it possible to do this by assigning some method to the SomeEnum?  I realized I could use TYPE.One.ToString("00")but I would like to have it self-contained in the enum and something very simple to use.

Comment: You may add Description to your enum and then get that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403065/how-can-i-assign-a-string-to-an-enum-instead-of-an-intereger-value-in-c

Comment: You can decorate the values with an attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can do something like this :

```
public static class Ext {

    public static string ToMyString(this Enumer en ) {
         return ((int)en).ToString("00");
    }
}
```

and after use this like:

```
public enum TYPE { One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3 }
Type t = TYPE.One; 

string s = t.ToMyString();
```

Yes, conceptually it's the same as like declaring a string , but it's hidden inside extension method.

Other solution is: to simply avoid, at this point, using `enums` in that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a string to each enum element using the description attribute.

e.g.

```
public Enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Value A Description")]
    ValueA,
    [Description[("Value B Description")]
    ValueB
}
```

To retrieve the description value, use an extender class

```
public static class MyEnumExtender
{
    public static string Description(this Enum Value)
    {
        FieldInfo FI = Value.GetType().GetField(Value.ToString());
        IEnumerable<DescriptionAttribute> Attributes = FI.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false).Cast<DescriptionAttribute>();
        return (Attributes.Any()) ? Attributes.First().Description : Value.ToString();
    }
}

....

MyEnum EnumVar = MyEnum.ValueA;
string Description = EnumVar.Description();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use enums for that, but something like a Dictionary or Hash. Enums are there when there is a limited set of possibilities and you do not want or need a value. How it is stored is irrelevant.

Comment: Can u give me a very short example of how I could use a Dictionary or Hash. Another thing I was looking at was using a static class. What I liked about enums was they were type safe.

Comment: Lots of information to be found on the internet, e.g. http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary